# How do I change the anchor link in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/GpdgF/1935/) tree that I found on the internet(its not mine), and I'm mostly satisfied with it.
A node is generated like this:

```
<li> 
  <span><i class="icon-leaf"></i> 
    Name
  </span>
  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>
</li>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');
    $('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function (e) {
        var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
        if (children.is(":visible")) {
            children.hide('fast');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Expand this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-plus-sign').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
        } else {
            children.show('fast');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-minus-sign').removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Each node has a icon, a name, and a link. When I click the  element, the current branch expands or collapses.

I would like to change it so that the icon would expand/collapse the branch, and the name would be the link. The end result should be looking like:
  [image: THIS]

I'm new to html,css and javascript and I don't know what modifications I need to do to css/javascript to get it, can anyone help me?

Comment: The code for the tree to reproduce the issue should be in your question; not as a JS Fiddle.

Comment: I personally understood the question, and have an answer. The OP would like that instead of `i` element + name expands / collapses the tree, only the `i` element does and the name can be linked.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker is it better now?

Comment: @Djizeus It's not just a matter of 'understanding' the question; it's a matter of having the question in a state where if the external JSFiddle link 404s, this question can still be useful for future visitors. That's why we put questions 'on hold', to give the OP the opportunity to make their question complete enough to provide value for others having the same issue.

Comment: Got it, didn't think of the case where jsfiddle goes missing.

Comment: @Djizeus It happens often, unfortunately (though less than it has historically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt does not work because the click event handler is attached to the whole `span` element, which comprises the icon and the link.

To make it work, you have to make 2 small modifications to the javascript code:

- attach the click handler to the `i` element (which holds the icon) using this selector: `.tree li.parent_li > span > i`
- Adapt the references to `$(this)` to refer to the parent `span`

So the whole javascript code would become:

```
$(function () {
    $('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');
    $('.tree li.parent_li > span > i').on('click', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $span = $this.parent();
        var children = $span.parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
        if (children.is(":visible")) {
            children.hide('fast');
            $span.attr('title', 'Expand this branch');
            $this.addClass('icon-plus-sign').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
        } else {
            children.show('fast');
            $span.attr('title', 'Collapse this branch')
            $this.addClass('icon-minus-sign').removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$('.icon-plus-sign').parent().next().next().children('li').hide();
```

Comment: Thank you, but this creates another problem: The nodes that have icon-plus-sign and icon-minus-sign no longer change their icon when I expand/collapse them. Can you help me with this too?

Comment: Good point. But have you tried understanding the code? The reason is the same why the call to `parent()` was needed. Updated my answer.

Comment: I have tried but I have no experience with javascript and lots of it notations seem like rocket science to me for now. Thank you, I will accept your answear